# Apache Storm topology deployment problems

Tags: java, cloud, apache-storm

I have created a local cluster on my machine to try the deployment of a Storm topology, but I have a strange problem. So when I execute the topology in local mode all works fine but when I execute in the remote mode it seems not work as you can see in the screenshot below:
[image: Storm topology overwiew]

So at this point, I can't figure out where the problem is, I also have checked if the Kafka producer works, and this works fine because this topology uses a Kafka spout. Thanks a lot for your help.

This is the storm.yml

```
 storm.log4j2.conf.dir: "log4j2"

 storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "127.0.0.1"

 nimbus.seeds: ["127.0.0.1"]

 supervisor.slots.ports:
    - 6700
```

This is the stack.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
    nimbus:
        image: storm:2.1.0
        container_name: nimbus
        command: storm nimbus  -c storm.zookeeper.servers="[\"zookeeper\"]"  -c nimbus.seeds="[\"nimbus\"]"
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper
        links:
            - zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "6627:6627"
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./TopologyJar:/TopologyJar

    zookeeper:
        image: zookeeper
        container_name: zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
             - "2181:2181"

#    storm-cli:
#        image: storm:2.1.0
#        container_name: storm-cli
#        depends_on:
#            - zookeeper
#            - nimbus
#        links:
#            - zookeeper
#            - nimbus
#
#        #The following two comands
#        #are used for showing an I/O terminal aka Shell
##        stdin_open: true
##        tty: true

    storm-ui: 
        image: storm:2.1.0
        container_name: storm-ui
        command: storm ui  -c nimbus.seeds="[\"nimbus\"]"  -c storm.zookeeper.servers="[\"zookeeper\"]"
        depends_on: 
            - nimbus
            - zookeeper
        links: 
            - nimbus
            - zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"

    supervisor:
        image: storm:2.1.0
        command: storm supervisor -c nimbus.seeds="[\"nimbus\"]"  -c storm.zookeeper.servers="[\"zookeeper\"]"
        container_name: supervisor
        depends_on:
            - nimbus
            - zookeeper
            - redis
        links:
            - nimbus
            - zookeeper
            - redis
        restart: always

    redis:
        image: redis
        container_name: redis
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"

#web iu for manage redis
    redis-commander:
        container_name: redis-commander
        hostname: redis-commander
        image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
        restart: always
        environment:
        - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
        ports:
            - "8081:8081"
        depends_on:
            - redis
```

Comment: It looks like the topology isn't running on any workers (it shows 0 under Num Workers). Did you start the supervisor daemon? If you did, take a look at the logs in storm/logs, they might tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: Yes, the daemons are all up. But I find this error "ava.lang.Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field UI_PORT must be an Integer within type range." but the UI_Port is the default port

Comment: Could you post your storm.yaml? That error is complaining about something in the Storm config.

Comment: @StigRohdeDøssing done

Comment: Ok, the config looks fine. I think you should try building one of the storm-starter topologies, and deploying it on your cluster. This will tell you whether the issue is with your topology jar, or with the cluster setup. You will find the storm-starter project in the `examples` directory in your install. Try e.g. running the ExclamationTopology https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/starter/ExclamationTopology.java

Comment: This seems a windows OS problem because I switch on my linux machine an all seems work

Comment: Ah. Are you running the Storm processes as administrator? Storm needs to create some symlinks when setting up workers, and on Windows, this is only possible as admin.

Comment: yes I have run all as admin, but now I have the same problem with docker swarm and I don't know why, I will post the stack.yml file, this now works without kafka